# Could I use docker or something similar to deploy windows application?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, docker

I am running a game on Windows, and it requires every OS can only run one. And If I want to run more, currently I open `vmware` and run the game inside. But the problem is it takes too much memory and disk to run a whole another virtual OS. I know `docker` will reduce this, but it doesn't seem to support Windows.

Am I right? If so, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker uses LXC (linux containers) so cannot run a Windows operating system.

You can use docker on Windows using a [boot2docker](http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/) VM, but this is not the same as docker running a Windows operating system (your containers will run unix based operating systems inside the `boot2docker` VM).

To do what you're after, you'll need to use separate VMs.

Comment: So the answer comes to `You can't yet`?

Comment: Well, the answer is "you can't", without the "yet" :)